# Using jooq to generate a InsertSelect

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I wanna a function like this in Factory:

```
public final <R extends Record> InsertValuesStep<R> insertInto(Table<R> into, Collection<? extends   Field<?>> fields, Select<?> select) {
    return new org.jooq.impl.InsertSelectQueryImpl<R>(this, into, fields, select);
}
```

but i cann't access org.jooq.impl.InsertSelectQueryImpl, and i wanna to use InsertOnDuplicateStep to set onDuplicateKeyUpdate()

How to implemet it,  Lukas?

i wanna to get sql like this:

```
insert ignore into tb1(field1,field2) select  value1,value2 from tb2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. As of jOOQ 3.0, there is currently an API design flaw that prevents you from combining `INSERT .. SELECT` with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE / IGNORE` clauses in jOOQ. I have registered [#2529](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2529) for this issue.

A similar flaw has already been registered as [#2123](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2123), where `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE / IGNORE` cannot be combined with a `RETURNING` clause.

There is currently no workaround for this issue, I'm afraid.

Comment: Does this limitation affect INSERT .. SELECT with RETURNING as well?

Comment: @GuiSim: Yes, as of jOOQ 3.2, it does indeed: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2123